# Android studio keep internet connection alive when key is locked

Tags: android, keep-alive

I'm on android studio. 10 minutes later it disconnects the internet.

```
I want to keep it on all the time without disconnecting the internet in the background.
```

Always keep the internet on in the background

Comment: how do you know that Android Studio is cutting of your connection? I very doubt, sooner you have a network or OS problem...

Comment: When I play the internet radio while the key is locked in the background, it does not cut out.